# Qt manually create color ramp rectangular QIcon

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a rectangular `QIcon` (say, 128 x 16), with pixel colors I will fill manually with a color ramp.

To do this I thought of manually creating a `QPixmap` of size 128 x 16 and filling it manually, and then creating the QIcon from it.

Is this correct? Is there a better way of doing so?

**Plus**

What I already have in memory is an `std::vector<>` with all the colors in the ramp. Is there a way to use this directly?

Comment: You could do a [linear gradient](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineargradient.html) and a mask, more or less like [described here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/38897/attempt-to-create-a-circular-mask-over-the-image/2)

Comment: @LaurIvan actually I have an `std::vector<>` with the colors I want in the ramp, Is there any way to pass it more directly to create the icon?